# Capture HTTP request packets from my iPhone

Tags: iphone, http, capture

I want to monitor the HTTP traffic sent/received from my iPhone. The iphone is connected to the Internet via my wifi router.
I want to capture packets from my windows 7 station.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a few options here:

- If your wireless router has a port mirroring or port spanning feature, turn it on and point it at your workstation's IP. Use [`Wireshark`](http://www.wireshark.org/) on your workstation to look at the packets arriving on the interface assigned to that IP.
- If your workstation has a wireless card, get [`Connectify`](http://connectify.me/) for Windows 7 (turns wireless card into Wifi Hotspot). Connect iPhone through Windows 7 wireless, and workstation through ethernet to the internet. Your workstation will effectively act as a router for your iPhone and you will be able to record iPhone's packets passing through it.
- Get an ethernet hub (make sure it is not a switch, you won't see all packets on every interface with a switch), and connect your workstation, wifi router and internet to it.
- Get a switch with port mirroring feature, configure port mirroring to forward a copy of all packets to your workstation.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that I wish someone would have mentioned to me is pfSense. This is an operating system based on BSD made to serve as a firewall. Top of the line routers have, say 400 Mhz of processing speed, and unimpressive amounts of ram. The lowest-end computer you'll find these days has better specs than that, and of course, it's upgradeable. You don't have to bother with those terrible Cisco licenses (no DHCP with no license, 20 DHCP users at one license level, 100 users at an higher lever? Ludicrous), etc. Best of all, you have "root' access to the system, so you can run whatever you want on it (including wireshark, say)!!

Make sure you have two sufficiently fast ethernet cards. You'll set your wireless router to not do NAT (because pfSense will be doing that), then you can get to work setting up your VPN server, etc. without thinking about cisco licensing, etc.